# Flex LineChart, LineSeries, DateTimeAxis, do not connect points on specific time distance?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a LineChar, with one LineSeries, on which i am drawing values ( Y axis ), on specific time ( X axis ).
The problem is that i don't wanna the points which is distanced on a specific distance in time ( let say 6 hours ) to be connected.

- Is there a way to make LineSeries with DateTimeAxis not connecting points distanted in specific time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [LineSeries styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/series/LineSeries.html).